# Is there a way in leaflet to get the coordinates of a map click when clicking on a polygon?

Tags: leaflet

It is easy enough to get the lat lng of a map click using something like:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    coords= e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng;
});
```

But if there are shapes on the map the function doesn't get called if you click a place covered by a shape.

Ultimately I want to produce a popup window triggered when a shape is clicked and populated with information based on lat/long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

You could bind your event listener on your shapes as well (possibly through an `L.FeatureGroup` to avoid having to bind to each individual shape), and you can even use that event listener to fire the `"click"` event on the map as well.

```js
var shapes = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

shapes.addLayer(/* some vector shape */); // As many times as individual shapes

shapes.on("click", function (event) {
    shapecoords.innerHTML = event.latlng.toString();
    map.fire("click", event); // Trigger a map click as well.
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/40/

Comment: This is great - do you know if there is a way to do the same trough geoJson layers rather than shapes?

Comment: Yes an `L.geoJson` is actually an extended `L.FeatureGroup`, so it should work the same.

Comment: EDIT: Figured it out, just had to add the geoJson layer in the same way to the layer group. THANKS!!!